# How to scrape all results from site with required location form?

Tags: html, css, r, web-scraping

I am trying to get a list of all infusion centers in the United States from the website https://locator.infusioncenter.org/. The site requires entry of either 'City, State' or 'ZIP' with a set radius between 5 and 100 miles. There are over 3,500 centers in the US, so I'm trying to find a way to get all of their information (Center Name, Address) in an efficient manner.

I noticed that the URL does not update with a specific search, but I still thought I'd try out a function with a large vector of zip codes and the CSS Selector for the information I am after:

```
get_infusion_centers <- function(zip) {
  url <- paste0("https://locator.infusioncenter.org/?zip=", zip)
  page <- read_html(url)

 locations <- page %>%
    html_nodes("#root > div > div > div.locator-container.flex.flex1 > div.locator-form.flex.column > div.flex1.scrollY > div.locator-results-container > div > div:nth-child(1) > a > div > div") %>%
    html_text()
  
  return(data.frame(zip = zip, locations = locations))
}
```

I received the following error `Error in data.frame(zip = zip, locations = locations) :  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0` when I tried that, which I gather means the location scraping was not effective.

I am new to web scraping and I appreciate any help you all can offer. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately I can't access your website from EU. ```Thank you for your interest in using the National Infusion Center Association's Infusion Center Locator.

This resource is restricted to users within the United States.

Repeated attempts to access the Locator from outside the U.S. will initiate security measures.```

Comment: I appreciate you trying - thank you!